# CSOM - overwrite content of file in document library without increasing version

Tags: csom

How to overwrite content of file in document library without increasing version?
We are using api where SystemUpdate is not available yet.

[image]

Comment: You can use `UpdateOverwriteVersion` method

Comment: There is not a such method in CSOM

Comment: There is :) , which version of SP are you targeting ? It is available since [Nov 2016](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-office-365-november-2016/)

Comment: We are using version 16.0.0.0 and cannot upgrade :(

Comment: as you can see the method is not there :(